# C++ SDL2 Image Loading different formats than .bmp

Tags: c++, image, sdl-2

I asked a similar question a while ago where I asked how I could load different formats with SDL2_image.h which helped me load images in my SDL program. The problem which occurs now is when I try to load a file with a different format than ".bmp".

For example - This code runs fine,

```
Img = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "./image.bmp");
SDL_QueryTexture(Img, NULL, NULL, &w, &h);
rectImg.x = 0; rectImg.y = 0; rectImg.w = w / 2; rectImg.h = h / 2;

if (Img == NULL) {
    std::cout << "failed to load image";
}
```

This prints "failed to load image" in console.

```
Img = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "./image.jpg");
SDL_QueryTexture(Img, NULL, NULL, &w, &h);
rectImg.x = 0; rectImg.y = 0; rectImg.w = w / 2; rectImg.h = h / 2;

if (Img == NULL) {
    std::cout << "failed to load image";
}
```

The images are in the same folder but in the second case I get an error. Is SDL2 image unable to load those kinds of files or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are missing initialization code required to process compressed formats:

```
IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_JPG | IMG_INIT_PNG);
```

Comment: When I try to use this it cannot find the specified module, is this something outside SDL2_Image I have to download?

Comment: @darclander SDL2_image binary distribution comes with libjpeg, libpng, ... dynamic libraries, and loads them only when requested via `IMG_Init`. You need to put required libraries into library search path (or most likely the same directory your executable is in).

Comment: Libjpeg and libpng are already in the specified search path but when I run the program with the code you provided me + an error handling event I receive the error message "libjpeg-9.dll" cannot be found, but they are in the specified path as mentioned above...

Comment: @darclander Are you sure that libjpeg has the same platform configuration (32/64 bit) as executable?

Comment: @VTT how can I see that?

Comment: @darclander You can use something like CFF Explorer. You may also try loading it manually by calling `LoadLibrary` and checking value returned by `GetLastError` if it fails.